# How to phrase this?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

Person 1: *I hope you can forgive me.*

Person 2: _______________________? *You're my best friend.*

*How could I not forgive you?*

*Why would I not want to forgive you?*

*Why should I not want to forgive you?*

What is the natural way to say this to basically say "of course I forgive you. Why would you ever doubt that"? Is one of my examples the best choice?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Funnily enough, you give a perfectly good example in your question. You could say "Of course I forgive you. Why would you ever doubt that?"

Answer (score 0):

Your first option, *how could I not forgive you*, feels the best to me. It has a sense of "of course I do", almost like it's out of the person's control - it's not even about what they *want*, they're sort of *compelled* to forgive the other person, because they're their best friend, you know?

The other two have that sense of *wanting* to forgive, so that feels like a different tone, like the forgiveness is a decision being made. The emphasis is more on that word, *want*. It's also a little more complex - just because someone *wants* to forgive someone else, it doesn't mean they *can*. Some things are too much, and can't be forgiven!

Your last two examples sound fairly formal written out like that, personally I feel like they're more natural with *why wouldn't I* and *why shouldn't I*. They both mean the same thing, but the tone for the first feels more like "is there a reason why I wouldn't?" while the second feels more argumentative, like they want to forgive you and they're challenging you to give them a reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

How couldn't I?
Are you kidding me?
What did you think of me?
Or, simply, Why not?